# how to format date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, formatting, sql-update

I am trying to update a date field in my table but would to convert the date format into dd/mm/yy.
    i have tried this method but it is still showing like this yyyy-mm-dd

```
 UPDATE MyTable 
        SET MyField = convert (varchar,GETDATE(), 101)
       where ID = '221'
```

Comment: What data type is `MyField`? You should store dates as `datetime` or `date`, not `varchar`. Worry about formatting when selecting or in your application layer.

Comment: The date is not store with a format. You format the date in presentation layer or when you query the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't consider formatting when inserting. Since the `MyField` is of data type `datetime` then just update it with `GETDATE()` like so:

```
 UPDATE MyTable 
 SET MyField =  GETDATE()
 where ID = '221'
```

Dates are not stored with a format.

And you should store date/datetime values into [`date` or `datetime` data types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx)

Then, when selecting these date values, you can use the [**`CONVERT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function as you did in your question to format the date. And you will find in this page all the codes and thier format. Choose what suits you. Something like:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), myfield, 120) 'With formatting'
FROM @table;
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/84468)

Comment: the data type of MyFied is just Date.  do i need to change it into DateTime data type?

Comment: @moe - `Date` is OK, if you didn't need the time part. And it will work the way I posted, it will accept the `GETDATE()` function.

Comment: thanks Mahmoud, but still it is showing this format yyyy-mm-dd.  how can i store it in this format mm-dd-yy?  thanks

Comment: @moe - Store it as `DATE` and use code `120` with the `CONVERT` function. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

moe,

date and datetime in SQL are stored without a format.  There no point in using format when inserting/updating... only when selecting.